# C++ matrix program not working

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I have to make a little program that does the following:

- Read a matrix.
- Write the posición where a number equal to the last one, first appears.

I have made that, it does not work and I really do not know why; I want to get the position if the condition is satisfied but I always get the unsatisfied condition even though I check it is mathematically satisfied:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int N=5;

void leerMatriz(int dim, int matriz[N][N]);
void posicionUltimoDato(int dim, int matriz[N][N]);

int main(){
    int dim, matriz[N][N];
    cout<<"Dame la dim de la matriz"<<endl;
    cin>>dim;
    leerMatriz(dim,matriz);
    posicionUltimoDato(dim, matriz);
}

void leerMatriz(int dim, int matriz[N][N]){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<dim;i++){
        for(j=0;j<dim;j++){
            cout<<"Dame el valor de la posicion y= "<<i<<", x="<<j<<" ."<<endl;
            cin>>matriz[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void posicionUltimoDato(int dim, int matriz[N][N]){
    bool trobat=false;
    int i=0,j=0,posi,posj;
    while(i<dim && trobat==false){
        while(j<dim && trobat==false){
            if(matriz[i][j]==matriz[dim-1][dim-1]){
                trobat=true;
                posi=i;
                posj=j;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if(trobat){
        cout<<"La posicion es: "<<posi<<", "<<posj<<" .";
    }else{
        cout<<"No hay ultimo elemento repetido";
    }
}
```

Comment: "It does not work" is not a good problem description. What output do you expect and what output do you get ?

Comment: Thank you, new data in the original post

Comment: 'matriz[i][j]==matriz[i-1][j-1]' this does not look right. It will access out of bound data at the matrix corners

Comment: I thought 'matriz[i-1][j-1]' was used to acces to the last matrix position. Is not that for?

Comment: If i is 0, what is i-1?

Comment: I think I should change 'if(matriz[i][j]==matriz[i-1][j-1]){' to 'if(matriz[i][j]==matriz[N-1][N-1]){' but I still get the same

Comment: @user - You have some edge effects, like `matriz[0][j]` cannot be equal to the previous one, because there isn't any.

Comment: I made an other mistake with 'if(matriz[i][j]==matriz[N-1][N-1]){' and I should change it to 'if(matriz[i][j]==matriz[dim-1][dim-1]){' because 'dim' is the real matrix dimension that the user inputs. Now It does it well for the first row of the matrix but not for the others... @BoPersson I am trying to find that matriz[0][j] is equal to the last value of the matrix. Thank you!